# getting openssl error running on iron.io

Tags: iron.io, ironworker

I get the following error when trying to run a worker on iron.io:

```
http.rb:920:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

The ruby file that makes the outbound restclient POST to the server works when I run it locally  as well as on heroku.

So I know that it is possible to make the call without the error.

I didn't have the problem before, but now started getting it, but not sure how to fix it given that I am running off of the same gems and ruby environment 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem, here is the [issue](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/321).

Solution from github ticket:

```
res = RestClient::Request.execute :method => :post, :url => url, :ssl_version => 'SSLv23'
```

or

```
:ssl_version => 'TLSv1'
```

Comment: Gem was updated, and now it works without any additional params like :ssl_version